# Creating new smartform data using Ektron ContentTypes

Tags: ektron

Ektron 8.0.1 SP1

I am using SmartForms and Content Types to read (and hopefully write) data.  I can read data but now I am attempting to write a new record similar to the following.

```
ContentTypeManager<member> contentTypeManager = new ContentTypeManager<member>();
ContentType<member> newmem = new ContentType<member>();

newmem.SmartForm.details.field1 = "Chuck"; // This line throws 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error
newmem.SmartForm.details.field2 = "Norris";
contentTypeManager.Update(newmem);
```

I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for that first assignment line. What am I missing?

I am having trouble finding good documentation on ContentTypes for 8.0.1 now that the Ektron website has been redesigned.

Thx.

Comment: Zach looking for some clarification:
Are you trying to modify a smartform schema itself? Or are you attempting to create content BASED on a smartform/xml schema?

Comment: I want to add new content

Comment: These methods for "adding" are both good but am I not allowed to create a new object and set the values?  I get the error when I try to set newmem.SmartForm.details.field1 = "Chuck";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying, to ADD content to a folder that has a smartform assigned to it, the basic code block should get you started: (Note: the Html attribute of the content is simply the xml matched to the schema you created)

```
Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager cmanager = new Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager();
Ektron.Cms.ContentData cdata = new ContentData();
cdata.FolderId = 0;
cdata.XmlConfiguration.Id = 0; //SMARTFORM ID HERE
cdata.Html = "<root><field1>field1 value</field1><field2>field2 value</field2></root>";
cmanager.Add(cdata);
```

Comment: I thought I remembered there being a way to add new data using Content Types.  contentManager.Update() does update an existing content if I load the object and then make changes, correct?

Comment: So if I have a folder which has a smartform I can use the above code to add new form or update an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

You could update ContentTypes.cs to include an Add method. Just copy the Update method and change `contentManager.Update` to `contentManager.Add`.

```
    public void Add(ContentType<T> contentType)
    {
        Initialize();
        contentType.Content.Html = Ektron.Cms.EkXml.Serialize(typeof(T), contentType.SmartForm);
        contentManager.Add(contentType.Content);
    }
```

Unfortunately, `contentManager.Add` returns `void`. Ideally it should return the new content ID.

Comment: I like that. In my case, the content Id is not so important.