# Using Ektron PageBuilder to instantiate new SmartForm content

Tags: c#, ektron

I'm attempting to create a page that will take in given information from a form and create a new SmartForm in a given folder with a specific Template and SmartForm configuration.

The issue is that I have no clue how this could be accomplished. The closest information I could find was the code snippet give here: https://developer.ektron.com/Templates/CodeLibraryDetail.aspx?id=509&blogid=116 but from what I can see this doesn't associate the created content with a specific SmartForm configuration, just a title, folder, template, language, alias, summery, and metadata. Am I just not understanding what I'm seeing here?

Once I understand how to instantiate a new SmartForm it shouldn't be any trouble to populate the fields given a properly made input form. But without a way to specify which SmartForm configuration I want to use I see no way to fill in the proper fields.

Can anyone help me understand how this could be done?

note: I am using Ektron 8.0.2, not the current 9.*

**UPDATE:**

So I finally came up with a solution and it's a bit long winded for this page so I'm redirecting to a formerly useless blog of mine. If there is demand that I put it here I will do what I can to move the final solution I came up with to this page.

I should also note that in the end, PageBuilder was not used in any way.

[Final Solution](http://jsl245.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-new-ektron-smart-form.html)

-- John

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (instantiate, new, content) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar a LONG time ago - I think we were on v7.66 at the time. This is from like 2007, so it's been a while.

My app took Word documents as input, reformatted the content of a table (specifically laid out by our writers), and imported it into the Ektron system as SmartForm content.

At the time I want to say I had to analyze the SmartForm XML, and set up our content accordingly. There may have been better ways to do this, but we had a really aggressive deadline and I just needed to get the content into the CMS as fast as possible. I think you can assign the XML of a smartform-based content...

This wasn't an easy thing to do, and there was very little on the Ektron developer site to guide me. I want to say it was a matter of creating a content in the folder, which had the smart form attached to it. (It's been a while and my Ektron fu is a little rusty)

Comment: To add to this, the best approach is to load the XML from a blank doc and use it to create a new item. It's been a while since I have done this as well, but you have to create your nodes and add the values and it's easier to do with an existing structure. Of course, unless something has changed and they made a way to pass objects in and convert to SmartForms.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help in this endeavor would be `Content Types`.  It's a way of mapping the smartform xml fields to a strongly typed .net object.  Ektron has a lot of really helpful info on this topic, and I'm pretty sure this will work in v8.0.2:

[Ektron Content Types webinar](http://www.ektron.com/Webinars/Details/Ektron-Content-Types/)

["Content Types and SmartForms part II" - Ektron DevCenter Forum Post](https://developer.ektron.com/forums/?v=t&t=1665)

The ContentManager class was one of (if not the) first Framework API class introduced, so there's a good chance it would work for you.

UPDATE:
You might also give this SO post a read:  [Creating new smartform data using Ektron ContentTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592620/creating-new-smartform-data-using-ektron-contenttypes)

Comment: Ah, there is what I was hoping to see. The update method. Perfect. OP should refer to this for a method using strongly typed objects.

Comment: I am not using PageBuilder but I am creating new content with a smartform. How can I validate to see if a content with the same title already exist?